# Is there a way to render IPhone mic input directly into memory without working with files?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, core-audio

I see that the IPhone core audio does not include audioDevice objects to render audio input directly into RAM.  I hear people talking about using files to do this(like speak here) but I am thinking there must be a way to do this otherwise.  Your thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `aurioTouch` sample in the iPhone Developer site.

Comment: thanks. I saw in another question here on stackoverflow.com that there is an issue with AurioTouch (posted 8 months ago so it could be fixed by now) The question also provides a quick fix for it. here is the link:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312089/auriotouch-sample-apps-audio-playback-thru-not-working