# Measuring Human-Flatulence Propagating Wave Packet on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, waveform, envelope

Using my iPhone, I would like to measure human flatulence in order to measure, quantify, and provide a statistical report based on various properties of the overall event quality.  Outrageous, maybe. Fun, definitely.  If I'm going to "release" an iPhone app, I want to do it in style. That's right, I want to measure farts/stinkers/toots.

So that bring's me to my question,

In order to provide an extremely accurate analysis, at a very minimum, I would need to be able to measure a propagating wave packet, specifically one that would measure the envelope of a burst, distance between adjacent peaks, momentum, and velocity.

**A propagating Wave Packet**

[image: A propagating Wave Packet]

As I am no sound expert of sound analysis, I was wondering if there are development libraries available for sound analysis that would provide a robust set of tools with the qualifications as I mentioned above?

For those scope-creepers out there, your ideas are welcome, however, leave ideas only as comments, as I am seriously looking for an answer to my issue.

***Note*** I am aware of other flatulence measuring applications, which measure purely on the volume and length of the event, but none that would provide the level of quality I am looking for in this ground/wind-breaking application.

***Note 2***  I'm absolutely, 100%, serious.

Comment: What the hell is wrong with you? Just Kidding

Comment: Oh my... If T-Pain can do it, you can do it!

Comment: You need to realize that you're going to have a hell of a time with your signal-to-noise ratio. I wonder how much this will drain the phone's battery.

Comment: +1: finally someone has the courage to ask what we've all wondered ourselves.

Comment: You could call your app *The Brown Note*.

Comment: It will never make it through the app store: could you imagine how bad for PR it would be if all the iPhone kids were holding their phone in the middle of their ass?

Comment: Also add data for the "components of the flatus by percentage" like Nitrogen 6%, Carbon Dioxide 46%, etc

Comment: This is a ploy to get people to put their phone down their pants, isn't it? (Maybe to put your phone down their pants.)

Comment: lol! (Plus random text to make 15 characters)

Comment: A nice example of vapourware. ;-).

Comment: @"ground/wind-breaking application." :)

Comment: Sounds like a totally different kind of cloud computing.  Just watch out for code smells.

Comment: =)) : "If I'm going to 'release' an iPhone app" - WHAT KIND of release do you have in mind!? =))

Comment: Suggestion for the name of the app :P : F4r7M4573R

Comment: A potentially costly app like this might be named: iFart Pro

Comment: Really?  Really?  Have you at least succeeded in making the app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look into FMOD and OpenAL

- fmod.org
- en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMOD
- connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx
- en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAL

Being written in c/c++, both of these libraries can easily be linked against standard iPhone code to be compiled against the ARM architecture of the iPhone.

They are both capable of extracting the information you require from the audio stream of the iPhone's microphone via the APIs provided by Apple.

Comment: Noted.  I'll definately check that out.

Answer (score 7):

I think there is some merit in this idea. There are already apps that measure wind speed using the iPhone microphone, and they are apparently quite accurate.

You could also incorporate face-recognition and human expression-analysis capabilities into this program in order to incorporate an environmental-impact assessment into you over all metric.

In a future release, you could measure the speed and acceleration with which other iPhone users are departing from the event instance, in order to determine an effective blast radius and strength.

**Edit:**

Since this is a project I think many people could get behind, I did a little more digging around. There is [source code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/aurioTouch/aurioTouch.zip) available for an iPhone application called [aurioTouch](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/aurioTouch/index.html), that seems to have most of what you want.

```
> The code uses: the AU Remote IO audio
> unit to get the audio input and copy
> it to the output the UI presents:
> - Oscilloscope view of the audio
> - time domain
> - frequency domain
> - Scrolling sonogram of the audio
```

There is some additional info on StackOverflow related to getting this working here:

[aurioTouch sample app's audio playback/thru not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312089/auriotouch-sample-apps-audio-playback-thru-not-working)
[AurioTouch & FFT for an instrument tuner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447059/auriotouch-fft-for-an-instrument-tuner)

Good luck, and may the wind be at your back!

Comment: *blink*
I just had a vision of the movie "The Dark Knight"... Made reality.

Comment: @Trevoke:  Really?  I was more reminded of The Spleen from "Mystery Men".

Comment: +1 for the environmental-impact assessment through face recognition.

Comment: "a project people can get behind"...how utterly droll ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the [FFT algorithm](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/howtofft.aspx) to find the "pitch" of the emission.